# How can i store the frequency of the tags in any website page in Hashmap?

Tags: java, html, hashmap, jsoup

I am using a paired Hashmap in which i am storing the tags and its frequency but i am confused that how can i store the frequency in a variable.
Code is as follows :

```
package z;
import java.awt.List;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Collector;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.jsoup.select.Evaluator;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;


public class crawler {

    static String url="";

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int val=0;
            String URL = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
            HashMap<Integer, String> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
            myMap.clear();  
            try {
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
                ArrayList<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();

                System.out.println("Number of tags by select(\"*\") method =" + document.select("*").size());
                for(Element e : document.getAllElements()){
                    tags.add(e.tagName().toLowerCase());
                    myMap.put(val,tags.toString());
                    val++;
                }
                System.out.println("The tags = " + tags);
                System.out.println("Distinct tags = " + new HashSet<String>(tags));
                System.out.println("Distinct tags = " + myMap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
               System.out.println(e);
            }



    }


}
```

How can i increment the value of val so that i can store the frequency of all tags? Do we need more than one variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to use tag as key, not frequency. So your loop will be like this

```
String tagN;
for(Element e : document.getAllElements()){
    tagN = tagName().toLowerCase();
    val = 1;
    if(tags.contains(tagN){
        val+ = tags.get(tagN);
    } 
    tags.put(tagN, val);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton.. But how can i iterate to get the output?

Comment: `for(String key : tags.keySet()){  System.out.println("\"" + key + "\" - " + tags.get(key) + " times");}`